# How to get number in the first line of a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

My input files are file_1.txt, file_2.txt, file_3.txt and so on. These files contains data such as

```
$ head file_*.txt
==> file_1.txt <==
----- Reset Loop 1 -------

Test #1
data

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
data

==> file_2.txt <==
----- Reset Loop 2 -------

Test #1

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
data


==> file_3.txt <==
----- Reset Loop 3 -------

Test #1
data

Test #2
data

Test #3

Test #4
```

The code I have right now to get filename and the sequence number behind Test only if the data available under each Test from the input file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
    FNR==1 {
        testId = ""
        split(FILENAME,f,/[_.]/)
        fileId = f[4]
    }
    testId != "" {
        if (NF) {
            print testId > "1_val.txt"
            print fileId > "2_val.txt"
        }
        testId = ""
    }
    sub(/^Test #/,"") {
        testId = $0
    }
' file_*.txt
```

The output i get from this code:

```
1_val.txt

1
2
4
2
4
1
2

2_val.txt

਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱ਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴ਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵ
```

There might be some problem in my OS or something else as there are weird characters in my output file. I have thought of an alternative of getting the number in the first line of the input file for the data listed in `1_val.txt.`

The code I have for this is `awk 'NR==1' file_*.txt` but I am not so sure where to insert this particular command in the script.

```
The expected output:

2_val.txt

1
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Edit: This is the exact command I am running to create the output files.

```
thulasyc > cat data_collect.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    FNR==1 {
        testId = ""
        fileId = $4
    }
    testId != "" {
        if (NF) {
            print testId > "1_val.txt"
            print fileId > "2_val.txt"
        }
        testId = ""
    }
    sub(/^TX PTP Command #/,"") {
        testId = $0
    }
' "${@:--}"
thulasyc > ./data_collect.sh ptp_log_reset_*.txt
thulasyc > head *_val*
==> 1_val.txt <==
1 
2 
3 
5 
6 
11 
12 
13 
15 
16 

==> 2_val.txt <==
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

The display of the content of the output files:

[1_val.txt](https://ibb.co/2qrWtCg)
[image]

[2_val.txt](https://ibb.co/w7t6wSs)
[image]

Comment: This stackoverflow help topic is relevant: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ed Morton sorry that i didnt include the first line in the input file. I have edited it.

Comment: [edit] your question to copy/paste from your desktop the exact commands you are running to create the output files and then to display the content of the output files.

Comment: @Ed Morton I have edited to show the exact command I am running and the display of the content of output file.

Comment: I expected you to show us output that includes those odd characters you've been asking about but there are no odd characters in the output files you added. So... are there actually no such odd characters in the output you get? I'm confused... By the way, those  files you provided links to are empty as far as I can see.

Comment: In the terminal it dos not show the weird characters when i **head*_val* but when i open the output file (2_val.txt) created, it shows the weird characters. I will attach the image of it since the links are empty.

Comment: Looks like using Notepad is your problem and the actual file is fine.

Comment: Yes exactly. I opened 2_val.txt in my vnc viewer, it shows the output i wanted. Just when i open it in notepad, there is weird characters.

Comment: OK, so you have a Notepad issue that has nothing to do with your question or the files generated from the scripts we've provided. You might want to google something like "Notepad issues opening Unix text files" and then ask a question with Windows and/or Notepad tags if you can't find the answer by googling.

Comment: sure, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    FNR==1 {
        testId = ""
        fileId = $4
    }
    testId != "" {
        if (NF) {
            print testId > "1_val.txt"
            print fileId > "2_val.txt"
        }
        testId = ""
    }
    sub(/^Test #/,"") {
        testId = $0
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file_*.txt
```

```
$ head *_val*
==> 1_val.txt <==
1
2
4
2
4
1
2

==> 2_val.txt <==
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Comment: i still get the weird character in 2_val.txt file.

Comment: Without access to your desktop (which I'm definitely not asking for) there's no way to debug that, sorry. The script I posted does what you want with the files you provided and whatever problem you're having with weird characters would not happen when you run the posted script on a functioning Unix box using the posted sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use awk? To do it in perl you could start with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#put your files here:
my @files = ('file_1.txt','file_2.txt');

foreach my $filename (@files) {
    my $test;
    my $number;
  open(my $fh, "<", $filename)
    or die "Can't open $filename ";
        print "$filename:\n";
        while(my $row = <$fh>) {
            if ($row =~ /^Test #.*/){
                $test = 1;
                $number = $row;
                $number =~ s/\D//g;
            }
            elsif ($test and (length($row) > 1) ) {
                print "$number\n";
                $test = 0;  
            }
        }
        close $fh;
}
```

Edit: Also your question says ' first line of a file ', however the data you posted seems to imply the files contain more than one test so this code takes that into account.

Comment: i really appreciate your help but i dont have perl libraries to execute this code.

Comment: Ahhh OK, I am curious what Unix/Linux system are you on that does not have Perl? Its always been my go-to for this kinda thing becasue even somewhat old systems have a working Perl, and its pretty good backwards compatibility wise. I have found AWK can be different on different systems.

Comment: @turtle FWIW I only recently had perl become available on the systems I work on and that's because I changed jobs, not because perl became available on that system. They're 3B20s used as the admin center behind major telecoms equipment. I've had other systems over the years that also only had the mandatory POSIX toolset, which includes awk but excludes perl, and we see questions asked here a few times a year from people who also only have the mandatory POSIX tools. Awk can be different on different systems but you can write awk portably to work on all Unix systems if that's a concern.

Comment: Fascinating thanks for explaining.